# Switching user accounts on minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

We have three people in a family sharing two computers (and two Minecraft Bedrock Windows 10 accounts). Let's call them Tom, Dick, and Harry, using Minecraft accounts A and B. So, Tom and Dick usually play together on a world. But Harry wants to play on that world with Tom while Dick is off doing other things. Tom plays on account A and hosts the game, and Dick usually uses account B and joins as a guest/member. Harry could use Dick's account B and join the world, but then he would have all of Dick's stuff and Dick might log in to find his inventory rearranged and his character halfway across the map from where he was before. I want to know if Harry could also log into Tom's account A and play simultaneously as a guest/member with Tom (though they'd probably share a username, that's not a huge deal since its just the two of them on the world), so that he can potentially start as a separate character and have his own stuff and not mess up the inventory and location of Dick. Would this work, and is there a way to easily log in and out between accounts A and B on the single computer?